# NTP time synchronization in offline machines

Tags: time, synchronization, offline, ntp

I have a couple of offline nodes in a cluster. I want their time to be synchronized, so I configured one of the nodes to be the NTP server.

This is the configuration file of my NTP server:

`# node's ip:192.168.17.11`
`driftfile /etc/ntp.drift`
`server    192.168.17.11`
`fudge    192.168.17.11 stratum 1`
`restrict 192.168.17.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap`
`restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery`

The problem is that the other machines can not synchronize their time with this machine. 
Is this configuration file correct for acting as NTP server?

Thank you,
Ali

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a long time ago but have you found a solution for that? I have the same problem and can't find any solution.

Comment: Hey, no unfortunately I didn't find a proper solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using 127.0.0.1 as the server IP you are not allowing other compututers in the LAN to communicate with the NTP server.

Try changing 127.0.0.1 by the LAN IP of the server in the configuration file.